# Jquery swipe between pages - swipe not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to integrate the Jquery mobile swipe to pages on my website using the following source.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html

I've followed the syntax and have added the files and structure to my website. However, it's only working when I click on the next/prev buttons and not when I actually swipe?

I've added all the CSS & JS code so I'm puzzled as to why it's not working. I've even added logs to the console after each swipe to check if anything happens and when I swipe it logs? I can't link to the page I'm working on as It's not live but heres the code I'm using:

```
// Pagecreate will fire for each of the pages in this demo
// but we only need to bind once so we use "one()"
$( document ).one( "pagecreate", ".page", function() {
    // Initialize the external persistent header and footer
    $( "header" ).toolbar({ theme: "b" });
    $( "footer" ).toolbar({ theme: "b" });

    // Handler for navigating to the next page
    function navnext( next ) {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", next, {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    }

    // Handler for navigating to the previous page
    function navprev( prev ) {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prev, {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        });
    }

    // Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        console.log('swiped left');
        // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
        // attribute in the original markup.
        var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );
        console.log(next);

        // Check if there is a next page and
        // swipes may also happen when the user highlights text, so ignore those.
        // We're only interested in swipes on the page.
        if ( next && ( event.target === $( this )[ 0 ] ) ) {
            navnext( next );
            console.log('Found next page');
        }
    });

    // Navigate to the next page when the "next" button in the footer is clicked
    $( document ).on( "click", ".next", function() {
        var next = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "next" );

        // Check if there is a next page
        if ( next ) {
            navnext( next );
        }
    });

    // The same for the navigating to the previous page
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
                console.log('Swiped right');

        var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
                console.log(prev);

        if ( prev && ( event.target === $( this )[ 0 ] ) ) {
            navprev( prev );

        }
    });

    $( document ).on( "click", ".prev", function() {
        var prev = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "prev" );

        if ( prev ) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });
});

$( document ).on( "pageshow", ".page", function() {
    var thePage = $( this ),
        title = thePage.jqmData( "title" ),
        next = thePage.jqmData( "next" ),
        prev = thePage.jqmData( "prev" );

    console.log(thePage);   

    // We use the same header on each page
    // so we have to update the title
    $( ".breadcrumbs h1" ).text( title );

    // Prefetch the next page
    // We added data-dom-cache="true" to the page so it won't be deleted
    // so there is no need to prefetch it
    if ( next ) {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", next );
        console.log('prefetched page');
    }

    // We disable the next or previous buttons in the footer
    // if there is no next or previous page
    // We use the same footer on each page
    // so first we remove the disabled class if it is there
    $( ".next.ui-state-disabled, .prev.ui-state-disabled" ).removeClass( "ui-state-disabled" );

    if ( ! next ) {
        $( ".next" ).addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
    }
    if ( ! prev ) {
        $( ".prev" ).addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
    }
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="archive category category-issue-39 category-42 logged-in">
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="position:relative;">
                    <div class="breadcrumbs hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs visible-lg">
                        <a class="breadcrumb-link" href="http://issues">Issues</a> <a class="breadcrumb-link">Market Review N°39</a>
                    </div><a href="http://"><img alt="Jackson Stops Logo" class="logo" src="http://img/logo.svg"></a>
                    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left: 2em">
                            <div class="menu-main-container">
                                <ul class="menu" id="menu-main">
                                    <li class="hidden-md menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-1754" id="menu-item-1754">
                                        <a href="http://">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3199" id="menu-item-3199">
                                        <a href="http://issues">Issues</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3198" id="menu-item-3198">
                                        <a href="http://topics">Topics</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3391" id="menu-item-3391">
                                        <a href="http://500k">500k Properties</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3400" id="menu-item-3400">
                                        <a href="http://www.jackson-stops.co.uk/downloads.html" target="_blank">Downloads</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav><button aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="user-logged-in">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <h1>Issue N°39</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page" data-dom-cache="true" data-next="issue-38" data-prev="issue-40" data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-title="N°39" id="issue-39">
            <div class="container">
                <article class="section featured">
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Richmond_TW10_£9750001.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">As central London would-be buyers and sellers hold back, the focus of activity has shifted to traditional family house... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/london-market/sound-of-the-suburbs">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://london-market" rel="tag">London Market</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>3</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Sound of the Suburbs</h2>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section white">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://country-market" rel="tag">Country Market</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>3</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cash Trumps Caution</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Cirencester_Herefordshire_71772_£1495000_IFC_Larger.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">Many of the business owners we deal with are better off than they expected to be right now and,... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/country-market/cash-trumps-caution">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://lettings-market" rel="tag">Lettings Market</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>2</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Rentals reflect new realities</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Norfolk_71893_£2000_per_month.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">As one traditional mainstay of rental activity declines, others are arising thick and fast, from all manner of new... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/lettings-market/rentals-reflect-new-realities">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section white">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://lettings-market" rel="tag">Lettings Market</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>2</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Sales &#038; rental interactions reflect new realities</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Cranbrook_Kent_£2800000_65858.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">From different levels of inter-generational wealth, to different expectations from Brexit and a broad social acceptance of renting, property... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/lettings-market/sales-rental-interactions-reflect-new-realities">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://international" rel="tag">International</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>2</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Tuscan bargains balance lower pound</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Tuscany_£POA.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">From Barbados to the Balearics, Brits wanting to buy are pitching against competitors whose dollars, euros and yuan are... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/international/tuscan-bargains-balance-lower-pound">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section white">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://new-homes" rel="tag">New Homes</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>2</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Off-plan sales boom in quest for quality and character</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/C3_Cirencester_69504_£1095000-1.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">Louisa Hooper of the Exeter New Homes team reports that even she has been a little taken aback by... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/new-homes/off-plan-sales-boom-in-quest-for-quality-and-character">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section half">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://home-stories" rel="tag">Home Stories</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>2</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Toyah Willcox</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2017/04/toya.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">Toyah Willcox was born in Kings Heath in Birmingham, in the family home her grandfather built around 1946. She... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/home-stories/toyah-willcox">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="section half">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <div class="article-meta">
                            <span><a href="http://private-finance" rel="tag">Private Finance</a></span> <span><span class='span-reading-time'>1</span> minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Beware the cost of 90% mortgages</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article-body">
                        <div class="article-image" style="background-image:url('http://wp-content/uploads/2016/08/private_finance_14_lg.jpg')"></div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <p class="article-sub-header">The number of lenders willing to grant 90% mortgages to first-time buyers is growing, but their costs compare so... <a class="read-more-link btn btn-large" href="http://issue-39/private-finance/beware-the-cost-of-90-mortgages">Read more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-fullscreen="true" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" id="footer">
        <div class="control ui-btn-left" data-mini="true" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a class="prev ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-carat-l" href="#">Previous</a> <a class="next ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-carat-r" href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->


</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I've published the page so you can see the code http://www.ukmarketreview.co.uk/issue-30

Comment: can you provide the html for it where you have used the above one?

Comment: I've added but I've removed the URL from the links

Comment: Hey I have checked the `URL` and its working fine as 
it  fires when user drag more than 30px over an element in the any direction.

Comment: Hi Swentansh, are you looking at it on a mobile or desktop? And what browser are you using? I've just checked on Chrome desktop and nothing is working for me :/

Comment: I got the error as it runs when you swipe using the button once and then after refreshing the browser it is working. Need to look more what is restricting it for the first time.

Comment: I don't think you were looking at the correct code as I haven't published it. Please see this link http://www.ukmarketreview.co.uk/issue-30 for the page I'm working on. Best to try it in mobile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165421/discussion-between-shaun-and-swetansh-kumar).